# PHP Submit form only if checkbox is ticked

Tags: php, wordpress, validation

I have a problem with a wordpress widget that I developed.

It 's just a form with an email field, a button and a checkbox.

When the user click on submit, I want to verify if the checkbox is ticked and IF YES submit the form...

My problem is that the form is submitted even tough the checkbox is not ticked. The page is reloaded.

Here is a short version of my code :

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['rules']) && $_POST['rules'] == 'Yes') 
{
        echo 'The checkbox was selected'; 
} else {
        echo 'The checkbox wasn\'t selected';
} ?>

<form id="form-invite" method="post" action="">
    <label>Your friend(s) email :</label>
    <br/>
    <small style="text-transform:uppercase;font-family:Arial;font-size:9px;color:#333;"<em>Multiple emails separated by comma.</em></small>
    <input class="kolom" type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
    <input class="button-primary classic-button" type="submit" name="send-them" value="Send Invitation"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rules" value="Yes" /> <span id="rulesInfo">I read the Privacy Policy</span><br/>
    <span id="emailInfo"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a simple `onsubmit` handler to the form, e.g.:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("form-invite").onsubmit = function() {
        return this.rules.checked;
    }
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vqVEF/

Comment: Thanks dude! I used jQuery to validate my form and I just added "return this.rules.checked;" and it does the trick. Wish you a nice day.